# swift3: Create subclass by classname

Tags: swift, swift3

I have 2 classes - a `person` super class and a `SuperPerson` subclass:

```
 class person { 
    var name: String     
    var age : Int 
    func instance(){}
 }

class SuperPerson : Person {
var power : Int
}
```

I have `className = "SuperPerson"` and I am using the code:

```
let superPerson = NSClassFromString(className) as? Person.Type
```

to try to create an instance of a `SuperPerson`, but the instance doesn't have the variable power - it does have age and name though

Can someone suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please verify that this code exactly matches yours. Capitalization matters in Swift. `person` is not the same thing as `Person` and `SuperPerson` is not the same thing as `SuperPerSon`. (These should be `Person` and `SuperPerson`.) It is also not clear what you're doing with `superPerson`.  Why do you say it "has age, name?" How did you know this?

Comment: I mean, when i create class with that code, variable superPerson has type Person not SuperPerson. (class detect by classname)

Comment: This code doesn't create a class. I assume eventually you call something like `superPerson.init()` to create an instance? While that's possible, you have cast it to `Person`, so there's no way for the compiler to know that it has a `power` property. But it's unclear to me how you're trying to do that anyway. I am having trouble imagining what the code after `let superPerson...` looks like.

Comment: hi Rob, beauce i dont known class i want create, i only known it is subclass of Person class and i want call func instance in person class. I try superPerson.init() but xcode error ( change to superPerson.type(of:init) )

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

```
    class Person {
    var name: String = ""
    var age : Int = 0
    func instance(){}
    }

    class SuperPerSon : Person {
    var power : Int = 0
    }
```

Now the initialiton should be like this

```
let superPerson = SuperPerSon()
```

Then check it has all properties name, age, power.

Answer (score 0):

You are misconnecting about object casting, you were **down casting** to  **Person** class and then trying to access property of **SuperPerSon**, I have made correction on your code please refer following code.

```
class Person {
    var name: String?
    var age : Int?
    func instance(){}

    init() {

    }
}

class SuperPerSon : Person {
    var power : Int?

    override init() {
       super.init()
    }
}

     //let className = "SuperPerson"
     //let superPerson = NSClassFromString(className) as? Person.Type :this was your old line

 //Corrected new line is 
 let superPerson = SuperPerSon()
 superPerson.power = 10

 print(superPerson.power)
```

PS: This code is written in swift 4 , xcode 9

Comment: I'm guessing `SuperPerSon` with both `S` capitalized is a typo.

Comment: i want cretae class by classname, i dont know what class will be used , it detect by className